# Multiple MySQL Servers connector in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a scenario wherein we have to join multiple tables from different sources. For example we have

1. `table1`, `table2` from mysql1
2. `table3`, `table4` from mysql2
3. `table5` from mysql3
4. `table6`, `table7`, `table8` from hive

We want to join all the table in the same query. How can we make single connector for all MySQL connections?

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" ->  "jdbc:mysql://host1:3306/ontime?user=root&password='ert',
  "dbtable" -> "ontime.ontime_part",
  "fetchSize" -> "10000",
  "partitionColumn" -> "yeard", "lowerBound" -> "1988", "upperBound" -> "2016", "numPartitions" -> "28"
  )).load()
jdbcDF.createOrReplaceTempView("ontime")


val jdbcDF1 = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" ->  "jdbc:mysql://host2:3306/ontime?user=root&password='xyz',
  "dbtable" -> "intime.intime_part",
  "fetchSize" -> "10000",
  "partitionColumn" -> "yeard", "lowerBound" -> "1988", "upperBound" -> "2016", "numPartitions" -> "28"
  )).load()
jdbcDF1.createOrReplaceTempView("intime")
```

Like, if we have 6 DBs, do we need to do it 6 times, or is there any better way to have a config file and connect from there?

Comment: A database in mysql is a schema. U mean mysql instance I predume?

Answer (score 0):

Forget it, this is not possible. 6 DBs are 6 jdbc's.

Comment: We cant use presto connectors in spark ?

Comment: You are then in the Apache Superset realm.